# While Creating Build for facebook sign up for Android in unity I am facing some errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

While creating Build with facebook SDK 13.2. I am facing some errors which says

> Exception: Cannot include plugin
> 'Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Windows/x64/zlib1.dll' (Key:
> zlib1.dll;None) since plugin with the same name and architecture was
> already added ('Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Windows/x86/zlib1.dll
> (Architecture: None)').
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.CollectPlugin
> (System.String path, Unity.Android.Types.AndroidArchitecture
> architecture, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
> pluginContainer) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PluginsDataFor
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
> :0)

is there anyone faced same sort of issue and any solutions??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY5sV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete some of the folders from FacebookSDK/Plugins - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/wiki/FAQ---Troubleshooting-Unity-SDK-14.0.0

e.g. If you are building for iOS you can delete the Windows plugin folder